# How do I receive an event when user presses Back button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I receive an event when the user clicks the back button in IE, Mozila, and other browsers (using jQuery)? I want to do something when the user click on the back button [Browser Back Button].

I have to add something I need to do something when it is handled like $.ajax I don't know is there any way ?

I mean receive an event when the user does it.

Comment: Those are two different things. Do you want to *trigger* the back button, or *handle it* when it gets triggered by the **user**?

Comment: Dont think this will require jQuery but instead just HTML DOM, using the history.go(-1), this will handle triggering the back button.

Comment: @kamiar: The edit still doesn't clarify. Do you want to make the browser to back (which everyone's given you the answer to), or receive an event when the user does it?

Comment: @T.J. - wow, that edit *totally* changed the question.  @kamiar3001 try and be clearer about *exaclty* what you're after, the terms you're using are very conflicting.

Comment: Why ? what is not clear please tel me ?

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, well the second sentence of the first paragraph was always there, but the question was **big time** unclear, no question. The title and the opening sentence were both asking a completely different question.

Comment: @kamiar: When you say *"How I can Trigger Back Button"* you're saying how can you make the back button happen. That is, how can you make the browser go back a page. Then your second sentence talks about the totally different thing of receiving an event when the *user* does that.

Comment: I just want to run $.ajax when the user click on the back button what is not clear ?

Comment: @kamiar: I've updated the question to deal with the problem.

Comment: @T.J. - Good clarification, he's looking for one of the history plugins it looks like, most would fit this perfectly.

Comment: @Nick: And I'm eagerly watching to see what people recommend. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I'd say the jQuery history plugin is *exactly* what you're after, [check it out here](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).  Specifically, [you can find the `$.ajax()` demo here](http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/).

Comment: Nick, are you using that plug-in in a production app anywhere? Certainly seems to work well from that demo. (As you can tell, I'm in the market for one; used to use RSH but it's a moribund project now, and I was never *entirely* convinced it wasn't a bit OTT...)

Comment: @T.J. - yup, used it in admin screens that are more complicated JS wise and it's been beautiful...much more so since the updates on the github branch I linked

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use  the .unload event in jquery.  It's not specific to the back button though, just to the fact that you're leaving the page

[jquery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/unload/).